# Can we have a more prominent chat room description?

Tags: feature-request, chat

Many rooms include often-repeated or important information in the room description:

> ### PHP
>
> Discussion for all things PHP - You don't have to ask whether someone
>   is here or can help. Just tell us your problem. If anybody can and
>   wants to help, they will.

or

> ### JavaScript
>
> All about ECMAscript and its various libraries. Please read the rules:
>   rules.javascriptroom.com

Can we make it more prominent, for example, an auto-closing dialog that only jumps when description has changed, and is disableable via a chat account setting (but is turned on by default).

It can be really annoying to have 6 users coming one after another "I have a question, can I ask it here?".

Comment: Still requires users to *read* which we all know a lot don't.